# String.Format с null параметром

Tags: c#, строки

Этот код:

```
Console.Write(string.Format("Value = {0}", (object)null));
```

не вызывает исключение

А здесь:

```
Console.Write(string.Format("Value = {0}", null));
```

будет исключение `Значение не может быть неопределенным.`. Почему?

З.Ы.

А эти примеры

```
Console.Write($"Value = {null}");
Console.Write($"Value = {(object)null}");
```

не вызовут исключений

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Напомню, что передача произвольного числа аргументов в `string.Format` реализуется через `params object[] args`. Особенностью такой записи является то, что если передать вместо множества аргументов ровно один, который можно привести к типу `object[]` - компилятор приведет его к этому типу, иначе компилятор создаст новый массив.

Соответственно, когда вторым аргументом передается null - этот null принимает тип массива объектов, отсюда и ошибка. Второй параметр `string.Format` не может быть null.

В то же время, если написать `(object)null` - то в качестве массива его передать уже не получится, и компилятор за кулисами сделает вот так: `new object[] { (object)null }`, а этот вариант совершенно корректен.

*Поправка: на самом деле компилятор выберет перегрузку `Format(string, object)` вместо создания массива - но это просто оптимизация*

Точно так же будет работать и вот такой вариант: `string.Format("Value = {0}", null, null)`, потому что два аргумента никак не могут быть одним массивом.

Что же до варианта с интерполяцией - у него нет синтаксической неоднозначности, а потому любой вариант работает.

Comment: *потому что два аргумента никак не могут быть одним массивом* – фраза немного странная, хоть я и понял о чем вы, но не сразу, надо как-то переформулировать